# How to mock a method when you add a new parameter in that method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I had a method in which I added a **new parameter**

Method before changes:

```
return view.transform(response, distance, tool, call);
```

Method after changes

```
return view.transform(response, distance, tool, call, new Address(street, phone, number));
```

In mockito I had something like that:

```
 Mockito.when(view
                .transform(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyBoolean(), Mockito.anyBoolean())) //
                .thenReturn(response);
```

now I tried to do something like that but it doesn't work:

```
  Mockito.when(view.transform(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyBoolean(), 
               Mockito.anyBoolean(), eq(new Address(street, phone, number)) //
               .thenReturn(response);
```

If I remove the new parameter from the method and I don't put the eq(..) in test, the test passes . How can modify the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Mockito.any(Class<T>)` for that parameter if you don't care about the details of the `Address` object.

```
Mockito.when(view.transform(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyBoolean(), 
           Mockito.anyBoolean(), Mockito.any(Address.class))
           .thenReturn(response);
```